# cmake and tesseract, how to link using cmake

Tags: c++, opencv, tesseract

I'm trying to build my application against tesseract, which i have installed through brew (working on mac os x).

While i can compile my application without problem using g++ and pkg-config, i'm not sure how to do the same with cmake.

I tried FIND_PACKAGE tesseract REQUIRED but it can't seem to find it. Does anyone have a sample CMakeLists.txt ?

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the only (or the easiest) way to use tesseract in your project with CMake is to download tesseract sources (from [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract.git) )
The build with the following steps:

```
cd <Tesseract source directory>
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../
make
sudo make install
```

Specify "Tesseract_DIR" environment variable to the  directory you just created for tesseract.

Then in the CMakeLists.txt file of your project you should have the following lines:

```
find_package( Tesseract 3.05 REQUIRED ) # 3.05 is currently the latest version of the git repository.
include_directories(${Tesseract_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(<your_program_executable> ${Tesseract_LIBRARIES})  # you can link here multiple libraries as well.
```

After the all just build your project with cmake.

Comment: This doesn't work on Ubuntu and probably some other Linux distributions. The reason is is that Tesseract doesn't export a `.cmake` file to `/usr/local/lib/cmake/`

Comment: Terrible idea and as a new C++ dev coming from other languages I don't understand why do people think that having global dependencies is good or managable. Download and build tessaract source locally if you don't want to use Brew or Choco or whatever your OS provides.

Answer (score 2):

I used the following findpkgconfig command, it works for me on MacOS with brew packages.

```
find_package( PkgConfig REQUIRED)

pkg_search_module( TESSERACT REQUIRED tesseract )

pkg_search_module( LEPTONICA REQUIRED lept )

include_directories( ${TESSERACT_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

include_directories( ${LEPTONICA_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

link_directories( ${TESSERACT_LIBRARY_DIRS} )

link_directories( ${LEPTONICA_LIBRARY_DIRS} )

add_executable( FOOBAR main )

target_link_libraries( FOOBAR ${TESSERACT_LIBRARIES} )

target_link_libraries( FOOBAR ${LEPTONICA_LIBRARIES} )
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are linking against the library and not an installed package, you can just add it like you would link any other library into cmake

```
target_link_libraries( your_project tesseract )
```

this is the equivalent of adding -ltesseract to your g++ command line

Comment: after I isntalled tesseract to my Linux Arch install, this was the best answer. why would I need to compile tesseract and link to it when the OS already has everything availeble. I did however also have to pick a language (dataset) to isntall. english seemed best. https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/tesseract/ in my case. Thanks Phil

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment on Long's answer due to lack of rep, but using

```
target_link_libraries( FOOBAR ${TESSERACT_LINK_LIBRARIES})

target_link_libraries( FOOBAR ${LEPTONICA_LINK_LIBRARIES})
```

worked for me, after using the same findpkgconfig method. Using:

```
target_link_libraries( FOOBAR ${TESSERACT_LIBRARIES})
```

gave me a linker error when compiling