# Use Tesseract in CMAKE project

Tags: cmake, tesseract, leptonica

I am trying to compile a cmake project that requires Tesseract and OpenCV. Everything is being done in Ubuntu 20.04.
But I have been struggling to get it compiled.
I compiled Tesseract from source and have been going through several SO posts and whatever article I find online, but still no luck. I noticed that Tesseract doesn't export a `.cmake` file under `/usr/local/lib/cmake/`, so you cannot do `find_package(Tesseract x.x.x REQUIRED)`.

Looking around, I see that people recommend doing it this way:

```cmake
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_search_module(TESSERACT REQUIRED tesseract)
pkg_search_module(LEPTONICA REQUIRED lept)
include_directories(${TESSERACT_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${LEPTONICA_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories( ${TESSERACT_LIBRARY_DIRS} )
link_directories( ${LEPTONICA_LIBRARY_DIRS} )
```

Which seems to find something. After doing `pkg_search_module(TESSERACT REQUIRED tesseract)`, I can see that `TESSERACT_INCLUDE_DIRS` is populated with this list: `/usr/local/include;/usr/include/leptonica`. This is despite the fact that Tesseract header files are located under `/usr/local/include/tesseract/`. Anyways, running `cmake` goes through without an error.

However, running `make` afterwards simply adds strange errors of

```
error: 'l_int32' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int32_t'?
   54 |     l_int32        num;       /*!< number of unknowns                     */
      |     ^~~~~~~
```

to my project. Even though I have not even included any header files of Tesseract or Leptonica.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38128260/cmake-and-tesseract-how-to-link-using-cmake) post is the only one that seems to be close to a solution.

I have also tried the following without success:

- Add the path to Tesseract and Leptonica header files directly using

```cmake
include_directories(/usr/local/include/tesseract/)
include_directories(/usr/local/include/leptonica/)
```

- Also tried to make my own `.cmake` file so that I can use `find_package(Tesseract 4.1.1 REQUIRED)` directly.
- I even tried to compile Leptonica library from source, but that doesn't help.
- Reading through the [cmake file](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) of the Tesseract project itself also didn't shed a light on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So Ubuntu's `libtesseract-dev` package unfortunately does not bundle its CMake config files. But that doesn't mean you shouldn't look for them first.

```
find_package(Tesseract 4)
if (NOT Tesseract_FOUND)
    find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)

    pkg_check_modules(Tesseract REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET tesseract lept)
    add_library(Tesseract::libtesseract ALIAS PkgConfig::Tesseract)
endif ()

# ... later ...
target_link_libraries(my_app PRIVATE Tesseract::libtesseract)
```

**Always use imported targets**. *Never* **ever** use `include_directories` or `link_directories`. Forget those commands exist at all.

This code will try to find the `Tesseract::libtesseract` target in the Tesseract CMake package. If it can't, it will look for a pkg-config module for Tesseract. If it can't find that, the build fails (`REQUIRED`) but if it can, the `pkg_check_modules` command will create the `PkgConfig::tesseract` imported target. The `add_library(.. ALIAS ..)` command adds an alias to make the target names match no matter which method succeeded.

You then use `target_link_libraries` to link your application to Tesseract. CMake will handle the usage requirements (ie. link and include directories, compiler flags, etc.) for you.

Comment: I think I should do `pkg_check_modules(Tesseract REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET GLOBAL tesseract lept)`. Because otherwise I get an error of:
```add_library cannot create ALIAS target "Tesseract::libtesseract" because target "PkgConfig::Tesseract" is imported but not globally visible.
```

Comment: You are running an old version of CMake. Upgrade, or add `GLOBAL` after `IMPORTED_TARGET`.

Comment: Thank you. :) Yes I figured. I have cmake version 3.16.

Comment: what is the minimum cmake version for which you don't have to add "GLOBAL" there?

Comment: @jwezorek version 3.18. Check the release notes here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/release/3.18.html

Comment: thanks. also in the above, how come you do not have to call `target_include_directories(my_app PRIVATE <tesseract something>) for it to find the tesseract headers?

Comment: @jwezorek - because you should never need to do that, ever. Include directories are `INTERFACE` properties that propagate between CMake targets. Ancient CMake packages used to set variables that you had to expand into target properties yourself, but that is horrible practice now.

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#transitive-usage-requirements

Comment: so if using `target_link_libraries` means you never have to also call `target_include_directories` what is `target_include_directories` for?